# Изменение стиля React.Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, инспекция-кода

У меня есть компонент, отображающийся в списках - UserListItem. Мне нужно при клике на него изменять его стиль на другой, а стиль предыдущего изменить на старый. При этом список хранится в  массиве `this.state.list`, а название стиля я передаю через свойство `this.props.bodyStyle`.

Я могу просто заменять элементы на новые компоненты с новыми стилями, однако это выглядит плохо. Может можно изменять стиль? Или может можно изменять свойства без замены элемента?

**Обновление**

Ниже код функции, которая также передается через свойство:

```
onClickUser(user, index){
    let list = this.state.list;
    if(this.lastSelectedItem !== null) {
        for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (list[i].key === this.lastSelected) {
                list[i] = <UserListItem bodyStyle="userItemBody" key={i} user={this.lastSelectedItem} index={i}
                                        onClick={this.onClickUser}/>
                console.log("change last selected item");
            }
        }
    }
    list[index] = <UserListItem bodyStyle="selectedUserItemBody" key={index} user={user} index={index} onClick={this.onClickUser}/>
    this.lastSelected = list[index].key;
    this.lastSelectedItem = user;
    this.state = {list: list};
    console.log(this.state.list === list);
}
```

**Обновление №2**

Немного изменил все это. Теперь у меня есть 2 компонента: первый - контейнер, второй - отображающий компонент.

Ниже код контейнера:

```
_getSortedList() {
    if(!this.props.items || this.props.items.length === 0) return null;
    let arrGroups = [];
    let users = this.props.items;
    for(let i=0;i<this.props.items.length;i++){
        let group = users[i].getGroup();
        if(group!==null && !arrGroups.includes(group)) arrGroups.push(group);
    }
    let listWithTitles = [];
    if(arrGroups.length !== 0){
        arrGroups.sort();
        for(let i=0;i<arrGroups.length;i++){
            let list = users.filter((user)=>{
                return user.getGroup() === arrGroups[i]
            });
            list.forEach((user,index,array)=>{
                listWithTitles.push(user);
            });
        }
    }
    let usersWithoutGroup = users.filter((user)=>{
        return user.getGroup() === null;
    });
    usersWithoutGroup.forEach((user,index,array)=>{
        listWithTitles.push(user);
    });
    return listWithTitles;
}
render(){
    return (
        <ListBox source={this.state.listOfItems} selectedIndex={this.state.selIndex} onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)} title={this.props.title}/>
    );
}
```

А вот код отображающего списка:

```
createListItem(item){
    this.index++;
    let bodyStyle = "userItemBody";
    if(this.index === this.props.selectedIndex){
        bodyStyle = "selectedUserItemBody";
    }
    return <UserListItem key={this.index} bodyStyle={bodyStyle}
                    user={item} onClick={this.props.onClick} index={this.index}/>;
}
render() {
    if(!this.props.source || this.props.source.length === 0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return(
        <div>
            <p className="ListTitle">{this.props.title}</p>
            <div>
                {
                    this.props.source.map(this.createListItem)
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Что плохого? Тормозов не будет, реакт разберется. Вся эта байда с виртуал dom для того и нужна. Покажите ваш код короче, а то я не понимаю что именно вам не нравится, может вы что-то странное делаете.

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка Добавил.

Comment: Зачем хранить в state list а не индекс последнего выделения?

Comment: Список насколько большой в теории?

Comment: this.state = ... - так делать нельзя в большинстве случаев. Состояние обычно надо мутировать через setState

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка Да по разному, поскольку список выводится при поиске. Но если я буду хранить в state индекс, то как мне изменять выведенный на страницу список?

Comment: Вы переусложняете компоненты, в этом проблема. По хорошему загрузкой данных для списка должен заниматься один компонент ("умный"), отрисовкой списка - другой компонент (глупый), отрисовкой элемента списка - третий компонент (глупый). И данные которые надо показать списку - это для него props а не состояние, они с точки зрения списка статичны и самим списком не меняются.

Comment: Вы еще не раскурили идеи реакта в общем, это источник проблемы. Это нормально, но вообще я бы порекомендовал посмотреть код какой-нибудь популярной штуки на реакте чтобы перенять общий подход

Comment: Жесть какая-то. В state'е должны лежать данные, а не элементы виртуального dom'а. Для этого есть rednder.

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка, react не станет разбираться, если изменить key.

Comment: @Qwertiy благодарю капитан, коммент "реакт разберется" был написан "в общем случае", когда кода в вопросе еще не было

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка А так хоть немного получше?

Comment: Ну за работоспособность не скажу (например вы кажется теряете контекст в createListItem), но идею Вы кажется начали улавливать. Я бы передавал элементу UserListItem флажок isSelected и определял бы класс на уровне самого элемента

Comment: Весьма полезно для поддержки описывать propTypes, чтобы видеть что тот или иной компонент может сожрать. Этакая добровольная типизация https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: users.filter((user)=>{
                return user.getGroup() === arrGroups[i]
            }); - можно половину скобочек опускать: users.filter(user => user.getGroup() === arrGroups[i])

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка Спасибо, попробую так сделать.

Comment: В общем не бойтесь писать очень мелкие компоненты. Идея не только и не столько в повторном испльзовании, сколько в том чтобы изолировать и уменьшать сложность. Я обычно стараюсь писать компоненты так чтобы по взгляду на метод рендер сразу было понятно что конкретно эта штука делает

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка propTypes я видел, только не захотел с этим в то время заниматься. Надо будет все это заново пересмотреть.

Comment: Это штука добровольна, но она очень облегчает повторное использование компонентов и их изменение когда-нибудь потом